# How to disable expanding/collapsing menus in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

They are so annoying. I just want simple menus without any collapsing or expanding crap.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on empty space and then "Group by" > (None)

[image: Image of right-click menu]